# Allocating Audio buffer[Windows driver]

Tags: c, windows, audio, driver

I want to use the following IMiniportWaveRTStream::AllocateAudioBuffer method which is defined in portcls.h.

```
NTSTATUS AllocateAudioBuffer(
  [in]   ULONG               RequestedSize,
  [out]  PMDL                *AudioBufferMdl,
  [out]  ULONG               *ActualSize,
  [out]  ULONG               *OffsetFromFirstPage,
  [out]  MEMORY_CACHING_TYPE *CacheType
);
```

But i want to use it in a C file. I found a structure which achieves the same but with one extra parameter.

```
NTSTATUS AllocateAudioBuffer(
  INTERFACE THIS,
  [in]   ULONG               RequestedSize,
  [out]  PMDL                *AudioBufferMdl,
  [out]  ULONG               *ActualSize,
  [out]  ULONG               *OffsetFromFirstPage,
  [out]  MEMORY_CACHING_TYPE *CacheType
);
```

The interface strucure is defined as

```
typedef struct _INTERFACE {
    USHORT Size;
    USHORT Version;
    PVOID Context;
    PINTERFACE_REFERENCE InterfaceReference;
    PINTERFACE_DEREFERENCE InterfaceDereference;
    // interface specific entries go here
} INTERFACE, *PINTERFACE;
```

What does this INTERFACE refers too? And how to obtain a reference to it.

Reference: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff536744(v=vs.85).aspx